# Sympy matrix determinant of polynomials is not a polynomial

Tags: python, sympy

I want to calculate the determinant of some specific matrix. I have simplified my problem and try to demonstrate the problem with the simplest code below.

My problem is :

- Every element in my matrix **is a polynomial**.
- But the determinant of the matrix **is not a polynomial**.

I suspect that it should be caused by precision or something else, I would like to know if there is other way to avoid this problem. I hope the code below can successfully demonstrate my issue, thanks everyone.

```py
import sympy as sp

class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.E = sp.symbols('E') # the matrix determinant will be represented as polynomial in E
        self.elements = [] # list of matrix elements
        for i in range(2*N):
            if i >= 2:
                self.elements.append(self.recursion(s=i, X=self.elements[i-1], Y=self.elements[i-2]))
            else:
                self.elements.append(self.recursion(s=i))

        self.m = sp.Matrix([[self.elements[i+j] for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)])

    def recursion(self, s, X=None, Y=None):
        if s == 0:
            return 1
        elif s == 1:
            return self.E
        else:
            return s*self.E*X + 0.5*Y # if change to s*self.E*X + Y will be no  problem

N = 4 # N=1,2,3 works fine
m = Matrix(N).m
det = m.det()

print("Is the determinant polynomial : ", det.is_polynomial()) # will get False
for element in m:
    print("Is this element polynomial : ", element.is_polynomial()) # will get True

print("The determinant looks like : \n", det)
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have a similar issue and I believe it is because sympy converts matrix elements to expressions even if they are initially defined as polynomials.. Supposedly PolyMatrix or DomainMatrix are supposed to overcome that but there don't seem to be any docs for it?